# Graph and table of values of cdf of chi-square

Tags: plotting, cdf-format

I am doing an assignment and have derived the following function, but I don't know how to graph it. I have a trial of mathematica which I have never used before.

$f(x)=a(23.685/x)$ where a is cdf function of chi-square and x is interval [1,5]

Also how would I make a table of values for the same function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Evaluate@ Table[CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[ν],  23.685/x], {ν, {3, 5, 10, 15}}],   {x, 1, 5},
    Filling -> Axis, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f[x,ν]"},
    PlotLegends -> {"ν = 3", "ν = 5", "ν = 10", "ν = 15"}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

```
TableForm[
 Table[CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[ν], 23.685/x], {ν, {3, 5, 10, 15}}, {x, 1, 5}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"ν = 3", "ν = 5", "ν = 10",  "ν = 15"}, 
                   {"x = 1", "x = 2", "x = 3", "x = 4", "x = 5"}}]
```

[image]